# Luna artificial satellite eclipses

Tags: the-moon

Have we been able to see the shadow on the Moon's surface of any artificial satellites that orbit the Moon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picture of equipment left on the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/picture-of-equipment-left-on-the-moon)

Comment: No. Just like the lunar landers are too small to see from Earth, satellites shadows are too small.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.

Any artificial satellites around the moon is too small and too far away to cast a shadow. The angular diameter of the sun from the moon is approximately 0.5°.

[image]

This means that a satellite has to have an equal or greater angular diameter observed from the moon than the sun. The formula for angular diameter is:

$$\delta =2\arctan({\frac{d}{2D}})$$

where $\delta$ is the angular diameter, $d$ is the diameter of the object, and $D$ is the distance from the object to the observer. Using the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter as an example, it has a periselene of around 20 km.

Substituting $\delta=0.5$ and $D=20 km$:

$$0.5° =2\arctan({\frac{d}{40km}})$$
$$\tan(0.25°) = \frac{d}{40km}$$
$$d = 40km \cdot \tan(0.25°) = 0.175km = 175m$$

Unless you can find a 175 meter wide artificial satellite around the moon, I'm afraid we won't be seeing shadows anytime soon.

Comment: Is "perigee" appropriate off Earth?  "Periapsis" maybe?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks, I edited it to periselene instead, which refers specifically to the moon.

Comment: Great answer! This diagram (found in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32522/12102)) may also be helpful here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_eclipse_types.svg