Are there any photographs of the ISS "Glorious shadow"?
A “Glory” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glory  is a bright spot or set of concentric rings caused by wave interference of light internaly refracted within small water droplets. It is commonly seen at the antisolar point from aircraft flying over clouds. It is centered on the aircraft’s shadow, if the shadow is visible.

https://atoptics.co.uk/blog/opod-glory
I assume a glory could be seen from the ISS. Are there any photographs of this phenomenon, and has the ISS shadow ever been captured in the glory?
The highest altitude for water droplets is the top of the troposphere (up to 17km in the tropics) Because of the ISS orbital altitude and the angular diameter of the sun, the ISS penumbra would be many times larger than the ISS itself and the umbra would not be present. The ISS shadow would be expected to appear (if at all) as a fuzzy dark spot in the center of the glory.
Has this been captured in an image?
Edit: I found this link https://www.livescience.com/planet-earth/weather/earth-from-space-warped-double-rainbow-glory-appears-next-to-rare-cloud-swirls-over-mexican-island  which claims the first glory captured from space was by Mediterranean Israeli Dust Experiment (MEIDEX) on board the space shuttle Columbia STS-107 flight in January 2003.


Glories certainly seem to be possible, o doubt the iss casts a visible shadow though https://www.livescience.com/planet-earth/weather/earth-from-space-warped-double-rainbow-glory-appears-next-to-rare-cloud-swirls-over-mexican-island

Yep, no visible shadow https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22816/can-we-detect-the-projected-iss-shadow-on-the-earth-surface

First Observation of Glory From Space (open access). In this case, I think you have answered your question with a "Yes" with the edit. Maybe it's better to just post that as an answer?

An airplane's shadow softens beyond detection by an altitude of about 5km above whatever it is casting a shadow on.  The ISS is ~400km above the ground.  So, that shadow is completely gone.  There would certainly be no umbra to speak of - even on the highest clouds (~85km).  Whereas the glory itself maintains angular size (increases size with observer distance) and so is visible at orbital altitutdes.  The shadow itself is not part of the glory and plays no role in the creation of the glory.  They just happen to be co-centered.

@Wyck ... good comment. Like to write it up as an answer?
